# Does the function movmean in Matlab create an average of all dimensions of the matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to smooth the temporal history of each pixel in my matrix- in other words, trying to smooth each pixel through both 'space' (mxn) and 'time'(third dimension). I am using the function movmean to create an average of each pixel in time of a 1000x1000x8 matrix.

I am currently using the following code to take an average, using a window size of 5, operating along the third dimension:

av_matrix = movmean(my_matrix,5,3)

This is creating an average as expected, but I'm wondering if the window is just operating in the mxn direction and not taking the average along the third dimension as well.

Comment: I think `av_matrix = movmean(my_matrix,5,3);` applies a window along the 3rd dimension only. So the window is a vector of length `5` aong the 3rd dim, not a `5x5` matrix. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Are you asking if the function does as documented or not? If you want to validate that that function only averages along the 3rd dimension, you can create a test image for which you know what the output should be, then apply the filter and check. The best test image here is `a=zeros(5,5,10); a(3,3,5)=1;`.

Answer (score 0):

To compute a moving average **along the *n* dimensions of an *n*-dimensional array** (the "window" is an *n*-dimensional rectangle), the simplest way is to use **convolution** (see [`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html)).

You need to be careful with **edge effects**, that is, when the convolution kernel (or *n*-dimensional window) partially slides out of the data. What [`movmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) does is average over the actual data points only. To achieve that behaviour you can

1. compute the *sum* over the kernel via convolution with the `'same'` option; and then
2. divide each entry by the number of *actual* data points from which it was computed. This number can also be obtaind via convolution, namely, applying the kernel to an array of ones.

So, all you need is:

```
my_matrix = randi(9,5,5,3); % example 3D array
sz = [3 3 2]; % 3D window size
av_matrix = convn(my_matrix, ones(sz), 'same') ...          % step 1
          ./convn(ones(size(my_matrix)), ones(sz), 'same'); % step 2
```

**Check**:

The following examples use

```
>> my_matrix
my_matrix(:,:,1) =
     6     8     2     1     8
     4     6     7     9     8
     4     5     1     4     3
     5     5     8     7     9
     3     6     6     4     9
my_matrix(:,:,2) =
     8     8     5     3     6
     8     9     6     9     1
     9     5     6     2     2
     1     7     4     1     2
     5     4     7     4     9
my_matrix(:,:,3) =
     6     5     8     6     6
     1     6     8     6     1
     5     5     1     6     7
     1     1     2     9     8
     1     2     6     1     2
```

With edge effects:

```
>> mean(mean(mean(my_matrix(1:2,1:2,1:2))))
ans =
   7.125000000000000
>> av_matrix(1,1,1)
ans =
   7.125000000000000
```

Without edge effects:

```
>> mean(mean(mean(my_matrix(1:3,1:3,1:2))))
ans =
   5.944444444444445

>> av_matrix(2,2,1)
ans =
   5.944444444444445
```